# Alternate for P4 Diff2 in Perforce Java API

Tags: perforce, p4java

I am having 2 Branch in Local Repo. I am developing a Utility JAR which compares the two Branch and list down the Changes(Files Changed, added and removed) done by various developers during the release Cycle

Earlier I was using P4 Diff2 command in P4 Command Line to list the changes manually and copy paste the output to excel to make a report. Now I am trying to do the same using Perforce Java API

```
p4 diff2 -Od //depot/rel1/ //depot/rel2/
```

Could someone suggest the alternate for Diff2 in Perforce Java API

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the `diff2` command does what you want to do, you probably want to just run that command from P4Java rather than find an alternative to it:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/impl/mapbased/server/cmd/Diff2Delegator.html

If you need an alternative because `diff2` doesn't do what you need, could you explain what it is you need?